# Django ForeignKey Relationship with an intermediate Table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the Goal Model and every Goal can have one Mastergoal and or multiple Subgoals.

Goals are connected with Links and every Link can have a different weight.

How do I achieve this with Django?

What I've got so far:

```
class Goal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='goals', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    sub_goals = models.ManyToManyField(to='self', through='Link', symmetrical=False, related_name='master_goals')

class Link(models.Model):
    master_goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sub_links")
    sub_goal = models.OneToOneField(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="master_links")
    weight = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

I can't just add an ForeignKey Field on Goal to itself, because every Link can have a different weight.

The solution I've got now works, but it feels wrong. I want to be able to access a Goal's Mastergoal like this: `goal.master_goal`

Comment: Why not add `weight` to the `Goal`, and use a `master_goal = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='sub_goals', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` for example?

Comment: Good point. I actually had a mistake in my thinking. Thanks for your comment now it's clear.